# Passing a list of Enums with generics

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have a method that builds the SQL for an in clause for a List of enum values when using a native query.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to make it work with a specific enum List, only a generic one.

Here is the method:

```
public static String toDbInClauseEnum( final List<Enum<?>> pEnums )
{
    if ( pEnums == null || pEnums.isEmpty() )
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Null or empty list passed to method." );
    }

    StringBuilder inClause = new StringBuilder();
    inClause.append( "(" );
    boolean addComma = false;
    for ( Enum<?> e : pEnums )
    {
        if ( addComma )
        {
            inClause.append( ",'" + e.name() + "'" );
        }
        else
        {
            inClause.append( "'" + e.name() + "'" );
            addComma = true;
        }
    }
    inClause.append( ")" );
    return inClause.toString();            
}
```

If I try to pass a regular list of Enum values such as

```
List<EventType>
```

I get the error:

```
The method toDbInClauseEnum(List<Enum<?>>) in the type DatabaseUtil is
not applicable for the arguments (List<EventType>)
```

I don't know that I want to define the Lists that I pass to this method in a generic way since that leaves room for error, but I can't figure out how to get around this error.

I have searched around and tried some different things, but none were directly addressing this question, so I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Make the argument `List<? extends Enum<?>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String toDbInClauseEnum( final List<? extends Enum<?>> pEnums ){
```

Or

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> String toDbInClauseEnum( final List<E> pEnums ){
```

Comment: Thanks @Volune, both seem to work, but I like the second because in Eclipse, I still got a warning on ? extends Enum since Enum was a raw type.

Comment: Yes, because the correct form would be `List<? extends Enum<?>>` for the first variant. `List<? extends Enum>` uses the raw type `Enum`, hence the warning.

Answer (score 4):

Even though an `EventType` is an `Enum`, a `List<EventType>` is not a `List<Enum<?>>`, because Java's generics are invariant.

Change the signature of `toDbInClauseEnum` to include an upper bound wildcard:

```
//                                                vvvvvvvvv
public static String toDbInClauseEnum( final List<? extends Enum<?>> pEnums )
```

This will work because the wildcard allows a subclass type, e.g. `EventType`, to be the generic type parameter.

Comment: I tested this answer as well, and it worked fine.  Thanks @rgettman